# Which fonts that are part of TeXLive have "real small caps"?

Tags: fonts, texlive, small-caps

The TeX font catalogue doesn't allow you to see which fonts have real small caps. Some fonts do not have real small caps (e.g. any of the `mathdesign` ones). But some do (computer modern and therefore `lmodern` and `cm-super`...)

I have restricted this to fonts that come with TeXLive, but I guess answers about other standard LaTeX distributions (MikTeX etc) wouldn't be out of place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two fonts with accurately designed small capitals are Palatino (`\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`) and Libertine (`\usepackage{libertine}`).

No. 2, p. 17 of the 2005 volume of the "[TeXnische Komödie](https://www.dante.de/dtk/bisher-erschienen/)" (the journal of the German-speaking TeX community DANTE) includes an article by Ralf Stubner and Walter Schmidt about the design of "real small caps" and oldstyle figures for the Palatino. The text is in German, but see page 21 for a lineup of "real" and "faked" small capitals.

Comment: Dang, doesn’t work with `fontspec`.

Comment: I believe `kpfonts` also has real small caps.

Comment: What about "TEX Gyre Pagella", which seems to be a heavily expanded version of URW Palladio (A Palatino clone)?

Answer (score 6):

`romande`, `berenisadf`, `electrumadf` and `venturisadf` support real small-caps. `berenisadf` and `venturisadf` also include italic small-caps and `venturisadf` offers outline small-caps for certain families. `electrumadf` includes oblique small-caps. See the documentation for details.

**Disclaimer:** I wrote the package support for these fonts though I had nothing to do with the fonts themselves.

Latin Modern includes oblique small-caps as well as the upright variety. I can't remember if `lmodern` supports this but `cfr-lm` (another disclaimer here) definitely does.

`romande`:

[image: romande]

`electrumadf`:

[image: electrumadf]

`berenisadf`:

[image: berenisadf]

`venturisadf`:

[image: venturisadf - italic small-caps]
[image: venturisadf - swash small-caps in upright and italic]
[image: venturisadf - old titling]
[image: venturisadf - further small-caps possibilities]

`venturisadf` supports a number of different fonts arranged into different families so you would not use all of these in the same document - they are just intended to show some of the possibilities. See the documentation for details of what's available and how to access what with package options and extended font selection commands.

`cfr-lm` oblique small-caps from Latin Modern:

[image: Latin Modern oblique small-caps]

Answer (score 4):

The newtx and newpx fonts have "real" small caps. As for the quality, I can't be judge of it.

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX does not fake smallcaps, so any font that gives you smallcaps has real smallcaps.

Comment: I refer you to section 4.2.1 of this document: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign/mathdesign-doc.pdf It's not LaTeX doing the faking, it's the font designers.

Comment: Try loading the `\mathpazo` package first with and then without the  `sc` option. The latter case seems like faked smallcaps to me.

Comment: The documentation agrees with you. The `sc` option uses family `pplx`.

Comment: Very bad, I though no TeX developer would dare to commit such a typographic crime! Still those are solitary cases, and are the exceptions not the rule. I this question was which fonts provide fake smallcaps, then it would make more sense.

Comment: @Seamus: Hmm? The way I read that, it looks the fonts in question are commercial fonts, and in order to get real small capitals you have to buy associated "expert" fonts. How are the people behind the "mathdesign" package "the font designers" in question -- it seems like they only did the *math* fonts, whatever that is supposed to mean...

Comment: @SamB that isn't supposed to be "faking" in a value-judgment sense, just in a "the package has fake small caps" sense. And by font-designers I suppose I meant package maintainers.