# Which LaTeX font packages contain real small caps and work with the "microtype" package?

Tags: fonts, microtype, small-caps, kpfonts

I'm wondering which font packages are available in MikTeX and TeXLive containing real small caps and also work together with the "microtype" package? For instance, `kpfonts` has real small caps but doesn't work with `microtype` as it complains that it doesn't work with non-scalable fonts.

### UPDATE

It turned out there are no incompatiblity problems between `kpfonts` and `microtype` (see [Getting strange error with MiKTeX when trying to use "kpfonts" package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31388/2634)).

Comment: Can you provide an example of code? I don't get any complaint.

Comment: It is most likely that you got `microtype` in effect when using the bitmap fonts. Using `T1` encoding should avoid such cases. `microtype` should work with most Type 1 fonts and (and OpenType fonts loaded by `fontspec`in future). For small caps, many fonts come with real small caps, `mathpazo`, TeX Gyre project, Latin Modern, Computer Modern, KP fonts, etc., However not all of them are good. Badly designed small caps is worse than without (For example personally I don't like the old style number 2 in TeX Gyre Pagella and the ugly small caps in Heros.)

Comment: Just a correct to my last comment, using `T1` encoding may not solve your problem. Usually use `T1` will cause LaTeX to load the type1 version of CM (if it does that at some point). But it seems recent version of TeXLive just load type1 by default. So I cannot guess where you get the bitmap fonts into the mess.

Comment: I asked this question as I had problems getting `kpfonts` to work, and as the error I got was related to `microtype` I assumed there was some kind of incompatibility. However, the problem turned out to be something completely different (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31388/2634), and because of that this question is an exact duplicate of another question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2894/2634). Thus I would request this question to be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm wondering which font packages are available in MikTeX and TeXLive containing real small caps and also work together with the "microtype" package? ...  `kpfonts` has real small caps but doesn't work with `microtype` as it complains that it doesn't work with non-scalable fonts.

As others have pointed out, the fact that you're getting this error message is not because of some fundamental incompatibility between the two packages, but because your document's preamble instructions must, somewhere, be loading the font in `OT1` encoding. Finding the offending instruction and replacing it with a command such as

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

should do the trick.

By the way, version 2.5 of `microtype`, available in beta form from [this site](http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/action=listall/order=-last_update), coexists just fine with xelatex. The package's "official" version on the CTAN is still 2.4., which unfortunately doesn't work with xe(la)tex. I've been using version 2.5 for more than a month now without experiencing any problems when using xelatex.

I believe there are quite a few latex packages that provide fonts with "real" small caps and also come with matching math fonts. Among them are (with no claim whatsoever to completeness!)

- lmodern [yep!]
- kpfonts
- mathpazo (Palatino-type font); load as follows: `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`
- mathptmx (Times New Roman font)

There is also the `fourier` package, which uses a font that's based on the `Adobe Utopia` text font (generally classified as a "transitional" font a la `Baskerville`). To get "real" rather than "faked" small caps with this package, you'll have to have access to Adobe's (non-free) `Utopia` font; if your system already happens to have this font, you may want to consider it too.

Comment: You probably mean `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: Yes! I've fixed the error.

Comment: If I use OT1 and **kpfonts** I've got no error or complaint from **microtype**.

Comment: @egreg: Could this be because `kpfonts`, unless there's an instruction somewhere to the contrary, switches the font encoding from `OT1` to `T1`?

Comment: No, **kpfonts** is perfectly happy to use its OT1 encoded family; in your system you certainly have `ot1jkp.fd`.

Comment: @egreg: I apologize for expressing myself unclearly. From page 2 of the kpfonts manual: "The encodings `T1`, `OT1` [and] `TS1` are fully available ...; if you use some accents, you have to work with `T1` encoding ..." Unfortunately, the manual doesn't state *which* accents require `T1`. Could it be, then, that the OP was trying to typeset words containing certain accented characters and that there was a setting somewhere that was keeping `kpfonts` from switching to T1? Just a guess, of course.

Comment: The presence of accents doesn't depend on the font, but only on the encoding. Of course, using accents with OT1 is not good for many reasons, not related to **microtype** AFAIK.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1527/discussion-between-mico-and-egreg)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see such a  message when loading the T1 font encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}

Foo \textsc {Foo}

\end{document} 


voss@shania:~> pdffonts test-2.pdf
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
UXEVUO+Kp-Regular                    Type 1            yes yes no       4  0
OSPQDZ+Kp-SmallCaps-Regular          Type 1            yes yes no       5  0
```

Comment: Indeed, I can't either now that I tried producing an example file, but it _did_ when I attempted to use it in another document. Strange. Anyhow, I am still interested in knowing which fonts are available with real small caps.

Comment: it is not a problem with the font, it is a problem with your loaded packages.