# Getting strange error with MiKTeX when trying to use "kpfonts" package

Tags: errors, miktex, kpfonts

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile the following very minimal example with MiKTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

The error I get is

```
hb/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(D:\dump\tex\tmp\test.aux) )Trying to make PK font jkpmn8r at 600 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The jkpmn8r source file could not be found.
Running ttf2pk.exe...
miktex-makepk: PK font jkpmn8r could not be created.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file jkpmn8r): Font jkpmn8r at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

It compiles perfectly on my Ubuntu machine with TeX Live 2011, but not on my Windows machine with MiKTeX 2.9 (just updated all packages as well).

I detected this when trying to compile my thesis on my Windows machine, which produced the following error:

```
[5
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable
fonts.
\@EveryShipout@Output ...@Org@Shipout \box \@cclv

l.47

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

It appears it has something to do with the `kpfonts` package since the minimal example compiles when I comment it out, but why does it work on my Ubuntu machine then?

Comment: It seems that the Kp fonts are not properly installed, since MiKTeX is trying to produce them with Metafont, which of course can't succeed.

Comment: Odd, since I installed it using MiKTeX's own package installer. I'll try reinstalling it when I get home.

Comment: It looks as if your pdftex.map is in the user profile. This means that you will have to run `updmap` as user (not `updmap --admin`) to update it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Sounds like a probable problem and solution. Will try that first before reinstalling the package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That solved it! Could you please post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks as if your pdftex.map is in the user profile. This means that you will have to run `updmap` as user (not `updmap --admin`) to update it.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you on such an old post. But can you give me a hint how to do that, where can I change the updmap ?

Comment: @AymaneFihadi `updmap` is a command that you should run in a command line. Google to find out how to open one in windows.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had the same problem and your solution worked.  For the coming ignorant like me, It is simple; you open windows cmd then type `updmap`.  Et voilà!

Comment: Thank you Aymane, this worked perfectly for me!