# pdfTeX error font ppl8r not found

Tags: pdftex, miktex, compiling, texmaker

I am receiving the following error message from pdfTeX:

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file pplr8r): Font pplr8r at 600 not found
>   ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

when I compile the following minimal working example (MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
c = a + b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to compile using TeXmaker with MikTeX on Windows 7. I manage to compile this MWE, when I run TeXmaker as administrator. However, I would like to run it as a normal user. Does someone know how to solve this problem?

I do not think that the answer to my questions can be related to the one from
[PdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ecbx0800): Font ecbx0800 at 600 not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267675/pdftex-error-pdflatex-file-ecbx0800-font-ecbx0800-at-600-not-found)

Comment: Why are you using `lmodern` *and* `mathpazo`? Never compile with admin privileges! This sounds like a permissions problem but I don't know Windows. I assume it has something like permissions, though. Or you need to update the font maps for your user?

Comment: I want. to use mathpazo. I tried to add lmodern to try to make it work but it didn't. It seems like a permission problem which I have no idea how to solve.

Comment: Probably you just need to run `updmap`. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31388/getting-strange-error-with-miktex-when-trying-to-use-kpfonts-package?rq=1). If you comment out `mathpazo` in the meanwhile, it'll likely work in the interim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works when you compile as an administrator, it is likely that you simply need to run `updmap`. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31388/getting-strange-error-with-miktex-when-trying-to-use-kpfonts-package?rq=1) for details.

Note that this answer is specific to MikTeX. If you are using TeX Live, you should ***not*** run `updmap`. If you are using TeX Live, see [my question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i) for information about why you shouldn't do this, as well as instructions for recovery if you read that discussion too late.